# How to freeze a bar in a UItableview

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitableview, toolbar

I've made a custom class that consist in a customized animated toolbar instanced in all my views. It works well in classic UIview using [view addSubview:]. The bar stays between the tabbar and the view. But in my tableviewcontroller, it follows the cells when I swip them.
I don't have Xcode right here so I can't post any explicit code, but I'm just looking for a hint.
Thanks
PS: I've tried to search it over stack and Google, but I think I use the wrong keywords (not so good english :p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which view did you add your bar?

Try add it to the superview of the tableview instead of tableview itself.

Comment: Did the viewcontrollers have a superview too ?

Comment: You can do something like tableViewController.view.superview

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try this tomorow, and make it solved if it is !

Comment: If you tableview controller don't have a superview, does it have a parentViewController like navigationbar or something else. If you do, you can do self.parentViewController.view addSubview:

Comment: I've finally added it to a navigationController.toolbar, even if it is hidden.